# SOLVED! PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR after moving to the new ec2 instance

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

**SOLVED**: After hours of research, I found the reason. Problem was the `ssl_protocols TLSv1.3` because nginx uses OpenSSL-1.0.2, I can not only enable the TLSv1.3, either I should update the openssl to 1.1.1 or support both tlsv1.2 and tlsv1.3

---

Eveything works fine before updating to the new ec2 instance type.

My problem is that when I enable the ssl connection (I am using let's encrypt), firefox returns this response:

```
An error occurred during a connection to example.com PR_CONNECT_RESET_ERROR

    The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
```

While Google Chrome says:

```
The connection was reset.
Try:

Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

After moving to the new instance, I also updated my `A` type record with new ip address

Even if I disable the ssl configuration (in the nginx), I can open the my web page (vuejs spa) successfully.

Here is the my nginx.con

```
user ec2-user;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    client_max_body_size 10M;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # redirect all other requests for port 80 to the https://example.com
    server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  www.example.com example.com;
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }

    # redirect https://www.example.com to the https://example.com
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name www.example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
        
        return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
    }
    
    # https example.com
    server {
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name  example.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;

        location / {
            include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            root /home/ec2-user/my_folder/frontend/dist/spa;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the certbot result:

```
sudo certbot --nginx certonly -d example.com -d www.example.com
Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
Plugins selected: Authenticator nginx, Installer nginx
Cert not yet due for renewal

You have an existing certificate that has exactly the same domains or certificate name you requested and isn't close to expiry.
(ref: /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/example.com.conf)

What would you like to do?
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
1: Keep the existing certificate for now
2: Renew & replace the certificate (may be subject to CA rate limits)
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
Select the appropriate number [1-2] then [enter] (press 'c' to cancel): 2
Renewing an existing certificate for example.com and www.example.com

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - Congratulations! Your certificate and chain have been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
   Your key file has been saved at:
   /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
   Your certificate will expire on 2021-08-06. To obtain a new or
   tweaked version of this certificate in the future, simply run
   certbot again. To non-interactively renew *all* of your
   certificates, run "certbot renew"
 - If you like Certbot, please consider supporting our work by:

   Donating to ISRG / Let's Encrypt:   https://letsencrypt.org/donate
   Donating to EFF:                    https://eff.org/donate-le
```

I have tried this configuration but nothing changed:

```
http {
    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
}
```

For port 80,  if I update the configuration like this, then I can access the my webpage from the port 80:

```
server {
        listen       80 default_server;
        listen       [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name  www.example.com example.com;
        location / {
            include  /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            root /home/ec2-user/my_folder/frontend/dist/spa;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
```

Finally in the security groups, I open the port  443:

Protocol:TCP, port range: 443, source: 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0

Comment: You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), instead of adding an answer directly into the body of the question. (And you should then also edit the question's title again). If you want to indicate that a question has an accepted answer, you can click the check/tick mark alongside the answer.